# How to disable "Forgot Password" on the lockscreen

Tags: security, lock-screens

[image]

I have entered a wrong password five times – now if I click on *Forgot Password* I can enter a Google account with password, then it will unlock the screen.

How can I disable or hide that *Forgot Password* option before screen lock to force me to factory reset?

Phone is not rooted, using Android 2.3.5.

Edit:
I have tried without Google account: after 5 try still the Forgot password, but than it is a Factory reset, so it is related to Google account.

Comment: What's the problem that you're trying to solve here? From what I can work out, if you forget your password you want to be forced to factory reset your phone immediately, with no other option for some reason?

Comment: exactly. With a Parental control app I am changing the password and I am locking the device. It is to easy to unlock. Take a look at Kaspersky's Parental Contro app.